# In App Purchase Auto Renawable Apple Side Notification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift5

I have integrated the renewal subscription and apple side callback url getting notification **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS** and **INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL** thats Ok. But where i am getting the renewal subscription there no coming any notification and cutting money so, how can i understand product is auto renewable process, and please explain all notifications type and guide me to manage from the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notification about actual renewal, i.e. charge of money. You should keep App Store receipts in your server and check for new transactions manually.

Here is article from our blog about Apple notifications: https://blog.apphud.com/subscriptions-notifications/